# How to determine that a selection has been cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection, getselection

I'm trying to find a way to determine that some selected text has been unselected.

I've tried using the `isCollapsed` property of window.getSelection(), however if you click inside the text range to clear the text selection it still reports as `false`. If you click outside the text range to clear the selection it reports as `true`.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6CC5/1/) demonstrates what I'm talking about.

What else can I use to determine some selected text has been unselected?

I only need this to work in Chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a timeout of 10ms

```
$(function() {
    $("#select").on('mouseup keyup', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        console.log(sel.isCollapsed);
        },10);
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/jdznj/)**